# should my custom ISR for IRQ0 (PIT ticks) issue an int 0x70?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, bootloader, bios, i386

So i was reading a source code of a bootloader that uses 2 custom ISR ( interrupt service routine ) one for the IRQ0 (the Programmable Interval Timer tick) and the other for the IRQ1 (keyborad), and the first line of the ISR for IRQ0 is `int 0x70`, i searched for a while about this int and i found that it has something to do with CMOS-RTC, but from [osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS#The_Real-Time_Clock) :

```
The RTC keeps track of the date and time, even when the computer's power is off.
```

so that means that the RTC is system independent so why would i fire this int ?

Also i noticed something strange, the ISR for IRQ0 does not send a `End-Of-Interrupt` signal, however the boodloader is working fine and the keyboard interrupts are handled fine. but if remove that specific line (`int 0x70`) the keyboard interrupts gets ignored and i will need to add instructions to send the `End-Of-Interrupt` signal before every `iret` in the ISR ( has quite a few, it has some local labels each one have its `iret` the execution flow is transferred to this labels after such conditions) given the size limit of the bootloader (510bytes + magic word) did the author use this trick to omit using instructions sized ~6 bytes to send `End-Of-Interrupt` signal or it is just a coincidence and the `int 0x70` is used for something else ?
what does `int 0x70` do, and why whould i need it when creating my own ISR for IRQ0 ?

the code is something like this:

```
;; es is set to 0
;; edit the IVT
cli
mov [es:0x08*4], word pit_isr
mov [es:0x08*4+2], cs
mov [es:0x09*4], word keyboard_isr
mov [es:0x09*4+2], cs
sti

[...]
keyboard_isr:
     do_isr_stuffs
     [....]
     ;; send end of interrupt signal:
     mov al, 0x61
     out 0x20, al

pit_isr:
     .tick_rtc:
           int 0x70
     .label_one:
           do_stuff
           [....]
           iret
     .label_two:
           do_stuff
           [....]
           iret
     [...]
     iret
```

Comment: the `keyboard_isr` uses `iret` i just forgot to add it.

Comment: There's no reason to call INT 0x70 from a timer interrupt.  Instead I would recommend chaining to the old timer interrupt handler.  Not only will that keep the BIOS clock ticking, the old handler will perform the EOI for you.

Comment: @RossRidge i think he used that trick to omit sending EOI (as IRQ1 is higher than IRQ8 therefore the IRQ1 (keyboard) will interrupt the IRQ8 thus the keys will be handled [maybe?]), the bootloader was basic and there was no OS, that is why he didn't call the old ISR of IRQ0. thank you for your reply. but still i don't understand what does `int 0x70` -in normal cases, when needed- do ?

Comment: In normal cases either INT 0x70 does nothing or disables the CMOS RTC periodic timer that generated the IRQ8.

Comment: @RossRidge okey i got it, thank you very much for helping me understand. Can you copy paste your two comments to an answer so i can accept it -if it is not a problem for you ofc-